# Sharing a Scanner between two threads

Tags: java

How can I share Scanner object between two threads so that I can pass value to Standard i/p stream in one thread and display in another thread?

I have created two threads as below:

In **Thread1** I used below code:

```
while(true)
{

//Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000); // if I used this it is printing ABCD
str = System1Class.scan.nextLine();
System.out.println(str);
}
```

In **Thread2** I use the code below:

```
String st = "ABCD";
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(st.getBytes());
System.setIn(is);
ThreadMainClass.scan  = new Scanner(System.in); // here I am trying to refresh the     global object "scan"
```

Here the 'scan' object is created globally in the class ThreadMainClass as:

```
public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

It is accessing by both threads. My requirement is: I want to display "ABCD" in Thread1 which is passing from Thread2. It is displaying If I put some delay so that Scanner object will be created before the line in Thread1:

```
str = System1Class.scan.nextLine();
```

But I don not want two use any delay. So is there any way that I can do? I want to display "ABCD" at that instant when it is passed from Thread2. Also in the meantime Thread1 should wait data from the console i.e. Thread1 should not wait for any notification from Thread2. If data is passed from Thread2 just get it and print it otherwise it should wait from console only.

I think I need a way to REFRESH the 'scan' object from Thread2 but I am not sure. :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may achieve this by using ManualResetEvent to synchronize 2 threads, thread2 will notify thread1 when thread2 already read the value into scanner.

Comment: @Thinhbk Does it mean that Thread1 will be going to wait notification from Thread2? What exact I want is I dont want to wait notification from Thread2. Thread1 should work independently waiting input from console. Also it should able to get the value from Thread2 at any instant.

Answer (score 0):

To display it the same instance its passed, you will need to call a method in the class that sets an `AtomicBoolean` variable to `true`. You will have to write a method that loops and checks that variable's truth value. If its `true`, then print immediately.

Also make sure that you're `synchronize`ing your read and write threads

You can also do this by **creating your own events in Java**

Read all about this method from this tutorial:

[How to create your own events in Java](http://castever.wordpress.com/2008/07/31/how-to-create-your-own-events-in-java/)

Comment: I have updated my post please check whether using AtomicBoolean is still applicable or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may synchronize 2 threads by using wait() and notify() method.

In global class:

```
Object wh = new Object();
```

In code of thread1:

```
while(true)
{

//Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000); // if I used this it is printing ABCD
//Wait thread2 to notify
// Prevent IllegalMonitorStateException occurs
synchronized(wh) {
    wh.wait();
}catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
str = System1Class.scan.nextLine();
System.out.println(str);
}
```

in code of thread2:

```
String st = "ABCD";
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(st.getBytes());
System.setIn(is);
ThreadMainClass.scan  = new Scanner(System.in); // here I am trying to refresh the     global object "scan"
//Notify thread1
// Prevent IllegalMonitorStateException occurs
synchronized(wh) {
    wh.notify();
}catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

HTH.

Comment: If I use synchronize as above then I am going to wait for Thread2 which is almost similar to using sleep(5000). This is not what I want. I want to assigned value to str (in Thread1) whenever there is input from console or whenever "ABCD" is passed from Thread2.

Comment: @Angom: the approach here is totally different from using sleep(5000), 'cause using sleep(5000) will not assure that the String value will be passed from thread2 to thread1, since there are execution paths in which the thread1 get the Scanner object before the thread2 initialize the Scanner object. See http://java67.blogspot.com/2012/08/what-are-difference-between-wait-and.html